# How to tell persp-mode to ignore some buffers by major-mode

Tags: persp-mode

I'm new to persp-mode and don't fully understand its API, noticed that the Magit buffers are restored and set to fundamental-mode when restarting Emacs, and the list of these buffers grows as I work on different projects, I would like to have these buffers added automatically by persp-mode to the `nil` perspective.

[image: screenshot of ivy-switch showing magit buffers]

Here is my current configuration for persp-mode:

```
;; parte de esta configuracion fue extraida de
;; https://pastebin.com/raw/Q1hK8cwi
;; fuente: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/d66s8r/how_to_get_the_most_from_perspectiveel/f0r42ch/
(use-package persp-mode
  :after (ivy)
  :custom
  (ivy-sort-functions-alist
   (append ivy-sort-functions-alist
           '((persp-kill-buffer . nil)
             (persp-remove-buffer . nil)
             (persp-add-buffer . nil)
             (persp-switch . nil)
             (persp-window-switch . nil)
             (persp-frame-switch . nil))))
  (wg-morph-on nil)
  (persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove 'kill-weak)
  (persp-keymap-prefix nil)
  :bind (:map global-map ("C-x x" . hydra-persp/body))
  :hook
  (after-init . (lambda () (persp-mode 1)))
  :init
  (add-hook 'ivy-ignore-buffers  #'(lambda (b)
                                     (when persp-mode
                                       (let ((persp (get-current-persp)))
                                         (if persp
                                             (not (persp-contain-buffer-p b persp))
                                           nil)))))
  (defmacro hfj-make-tab (name &rest body)
    "Select an existing tab, or create one and configure it."
    `(cond
      ((persp-with-name-exists-p ,name)
       (persp-switch ,name))
      (t
       (persp-switch ,name)
       ,@body)))

  (defun hfj-make-tab-f (name setup-actions)
    "Select an existing tab, or create one and configure it."
    (cond
     ((persp-with-name-exists-p name)
      (persp-switch name))
     (t
      (persp-switch name)
      (funcall setup-actions))))

  (defun define-layout-inner (name f)
    "Add layout config to hfj-predefined-layouts"
    (setq hfj-predefined-layouts
          (delete-if (lambda (a) (string-equal (car a) name))
                     hfj-predefined-layouts))
    (push (list* name (cons name f)) hfj-predefined-layouts)
    (setq hfj-predefined-layouts
          (sort hfj-predefined-layouts
                (lambda (a b) (string< (car a) (car b))))))

  (defmacro hfj-define-layout (name &rest body)
    "Add layout config to hfj-predefined-layouts"
    `(define-layout-inner ,name (lambda () ,@body)))

  (defun hfj-pick-layout ()
    "Switch to a new or existing layout."
    (interactive)
    (let* ((names (persp-names))
           (name (completing-read "Cambiar a maqueta: " names))
           (exists (persp-with-name-exists-p name)))
      (persp-switch name)
      (unless exists
        (switch-to-buffer "*scratch*"))))

  (defvar hfj-predefined-layouts '())

  (defun hfj-pick-predefined-layout ()
    "Create a predefined layout to be selectable from list."
    (interactive)
    (when (null hfj-predefined-layouts)
      (error "No hay maquetas configuradas."))

    (let ((layout-name-and-actions (ivy-read :prompt "Seleccionar maqueta predefinida: " :collection hfj-predefined-layouts :require-match t)))

      (when layout-name-and-actions
        (hfj-make-tab-f (car layout-name-and-actions) (cdr layout-name-and-actions)))))

  (defun hfj-persp-kill-current ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((persp (get-current-persp)))
      (cond ((null persp) (error "No se puede matar la maqueta por defecto"))
            (t (persp-kill (persp-name persp))))))

  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-n (n)
    (let ((names (persp-names-current-frame-fast-ordered))
          (count 1))
      (dolist (name names)
        (when (= count n)
          (persp-switch name))
        (cl-incf count))))
  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-1 () (interactive) (hfj-persp-switch-to-n 1))
  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-2 () (interactive) (hfj-persp-switch-to-n 2))
  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-3 () (interactive) (hfj-persp-switch-to-n 3))
  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-4 () (interactive) (hfj-persp-switch-to-n 4))
  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-5 () (interactive) (hfj-persp-switch-to-n 5))
  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-6 () (interactive) (hfj-persp-switch-to-n 6))
  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-7 () (interactive) (hfj-persp-switch-to-n 7))
  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-8 () (interactive) (hfj-persp-switch-to-n 8))
  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-9 () (interactive) (hfj-persp-switch-to-n 9))
  (defun hfj-persp-switch-to-10 () (interactive) (hfj-persp-switch-to-n 10))

  (defun hydra-perse-names ()
    (let ((names (persp-names-current-frame-fast-ordered))
          (current-name (safe-persp-name (get-current-persp)))
          (parts '())
          (count 1))
      (dolist (name names (s-join " | " (nreverse parts)))
        (cond ((eq name current-name)
               (push (format "[%d:%s]" count name) parts))
              (t
               (push (format "%d:%s" count name) parts)))
        (cl-incf count))))
  :hydra (hydra-persp (:hint nil)
                      "
Maquetas %s(hydra-perse-names)

^Navegación^      ^Selección^       ^Acciones^       ^Buffers^
^-^---------------^-^---------------^-^--------------^-^------------
_n_: sig.         _l_: escoger       _d_: borrar     _a_: agregar buffer
_p_: prev.        _L_: predefinido   _r_: renombrar
"
                      ("q" nil)
                      ("a" persp-add-buffer :exit t)
                      ("d" hfj-persp-kill-current)
                      ("l" hfj-pick-layout :exit t)
                      ("L" hfj-pick-predefined-layout :exit t)
                      ("r" persp-rename :exit t)
                      ("n" persp-next)
                      ("p" persp-prev)
                      ("1" hfj-persp-switch-to-1 :exit t)
                      ("2" hfj-persp-switch-to-2 :exit t)
                      ("3" hfj-persp-switch-to-3 :exit t)
                      ("4" hfj-persp-switch-to-4 :exit t)
                      ("5" hfj-persp-switch-to-5 :exit t)
                      ("6" hfj-persp-switch-to-6 :exit t)
                      ("7" hfj-persp-switch-to-7 :exit t)
                      ("8" hfj-persp-switch-to-8 :exit t)
                      ("9" hfj-persp-switch-to-9 :exit t)
                      ("0" hfj-persp-switch-to-10 :exit t)))

(use-package persp-mode-projectile-bridge
  :straight (persp-mode-projectile-bridge :type git :host github :repo "Bad-ptr/persp-mode-projectile-bridge.el")
  :init
  :hook ((persp-mode-projectile-bridge-mode . (lambda () (if persp-mode-projectile-bridge-mode
                                                        (persp-mode-projectile-bridge-find-perspectives-for-all-buffers)
                                                      (persp-mode-projectile-bridge-kill-perspectives))))
         (after-init . (lambda () (persp-mode-projectile-bridge-mode 1)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [commimt](https://github.com/seagle0128/.emacs.d/blob/dcc772d05da04042b39d1660f79f599e030188ff/lisp/init-persp.el#L117-L129) from the repo `seagle0128/.emacs.d`.

It adds a filter function into the list `persp-filter-save-buffers-functions` to do filtering **magit** buffers. So, we can use the below example to config the **persp-mode**.

```
(add-to-list 'persp-filter-save-buffers-functions
             (lambda (b)
               "Ignore temporary buffers."
               (let ((bname (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-name b))))
                 (or (string-prefix-p "magit" bname)
                     (string-equal "*ansi-term*" bname)
                     (string-prefix-p "*" bname)
                     ;; and more
                     ))))
```

Comment: This is a link-only answer, please make sure the answer is useful even if your links go dead

Comment: What @stefan said. Please summarize here the content linked to that actually provides the answer.